# Change function pointer from pointed function during execution

Tags: c++

Is it valid to change a pointer to a function (`fun` here) from a function which was pointed to and during execution (`foo`)?

```
using fun_p = void (*) ();

void foo ();
void boo ();

fun_p fun = &foo;

void foo () {
    std::cout << "foo\n";
    fun = &boo;
}
void boo () {
    std::cout << "boo\n";
}

int main () {
    (*fun) ();
    (*fun) ();
    return 0;
}
```

The reason why I want to do this is to run either `foo()` or `boo()`, starting with `foo()`. Once condition is met in `foo()` I want to change it **once**, and since next iteration (the code would be run in a loop of course), `boo()` is invoked.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: The variable `fun` is like any other variable. You can assign any valid value to it, at any time.

Comment: With that said, from a readability and maintainability perspective this is not very good, IMO. How would a casual reader know which function would be called at a given point in the program?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Said it pretty well. While yes, it's legal, it's not the most legible way of doing things.
One way of doing it, would be to create a separate function which does it for you. `handleFun1CallComplete` or something similar.

Comment: What about checking condition in a loop every iteration when you can do it only once? Thats the reason I think about that idea.

Comment: @ArturPyszczuk Likely [branch-predicted out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/430766). And jump indirection is not free. Let alone the fact that inlining will be much harder if not impossible. If possible unroll the first loop iteration.

Comment: Style suggestion: `(*fun)()` => `fun()`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Having a state machine (state machine design pattern) as well does not give a casual reader information which state is currently set, yet this is very common and good design pattern.

Comment: That feels like a case of premature optimization.

Comment: With a state-machine you can always say what happens for each specific state. With your function pointer it's not possible to know which function will actually be called, the state is hidden.

Comment: Also note the `&` before `&foo` and `&boo` isn't necessary. You can simply write `fun_p fun = foo;` along with `fun = boo;`

Comment: Depending on the context, an alternative could be to let `foo()` return a bool which is true when it is done. Then `foo()` can be called until it returns true after which a second loop is entered which calls `boo()`. This way you will only have to check a condition while `foo()` is running and avoid the issues noted in the comments above.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**: the function pointer isn’t “in use” during the call.  Consider that it might be a prvalue and thus not be stored anywhere:

```
(cond ? &f : &g)();
```